# SKSpriteNode with physicsBody auto correct orientation

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

What would be the best way to make a Swift SKSpriteNode auto correct its orientation after it has had a couple of physicsBody knocks and is now not in the default orientation?

For example I have have a 2D stick-man who gets knocked to the side by another object and would like the stick-man to tilt and reorient itself to the default standing position.

Comment: apply angular impulse depending on which side he is with possibly strength or more frequently applying the impulse the more the character leaned over

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done this in the past is to wait until the physics body comes to rest, turn off the physics engine for the stickman, reorient the stickman, turn the physics engine back on again.

Write yourself an action called standupAction which animates the stickman's reorientation, maybe just a rotate or a jump up. Then do something like the following.

Sorry this Objective-C not Swift, don't know swift, but should be easy to translate.

```
if (stickman.physicsBody.resting) {
    stickman.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    [stickman runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
              standupAction,
              [SKAction runBlock:^{ stickman.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;}]
              ]]];
}
```

The only downside of this approach is that sometimes it can take a full second until the stickman comes comes to rest. Box2d takes quite a long time to settle down. But it looks very realistic if you wait.

Alternatively, you could just check the orientation of stickman and if he is >45degrees off balance then reorient him with impulses. I find impulses to be very difficult to know how much force to apply when you need precise movement like this.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't thought of the resting property! 1 second shouldn't be a material wait in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update, I couldn't afford to set the physicsBody to not be dynamic.

My scene updates each node, similarly to Apple's Adventure game, as such I implemented the rotation in the subclassed SKSpriteNode's update method as such:

```
if (isTouchingGround) {
            if self.zRotation != 0 && !rotating {
                let actions = [
                    SKAction.runBlock {
                        self.rotating = true
                    },
                    SKAction.rotateToAngle(0, duration: 1.0),
                    SKAction.runBlock {
                        self.rotating = false
                    }]
                runAction(SKAction.sequence(actions))

            }
        }
```

Comment: Apple's Adventure doesn't use the physics engine to calculate gravity, etc. You're manually altering the rotation while the physics body is being managed by the physics engine. This could create glitchiness when the physics engine is fighting you for control over the character's movement. I would go with @LearnCocos2D's original suggestion, use impulses to rotate it back to 0.